# Microsoft Outlook: show multi-day appointments as boxes in calendar day and week view

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like to show appointments spanning several days the same way as appintments within a single day.

Single day appointments are shown with a white or colored box, covering the day horizontally.

Multi-day appointments are shown in the day/week header and are indicated blue or purple on the left side of a day. This happens even if a multi-day appointment is not an all-day appointment (i.e. checkbox is off) and I have a start and end time. I frequently have a hard time seeing appointment overlaps wenn acceping single day appointments.

Therefore I am looking for multi-day appointments shown the same way as single day appointments.

I am on Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A low tech solution but I found if you create the meeting for the first day only you can then right click copy it and then right click paste it to each of the other days in the calendar view.

Saves a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

One way around this is to set the event as a reoccurring event, for however many days it will occur, then it will show up in the day view preview window. I'm using Outlook 2013.

This really should be a preference the user can customize. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your multi-day appointments are scheduled as all day events while "single day" appointments are part of the day.  To get the same affect, schedule the multi day appointments as partial day (start & end time, not all day event) and repeat over several days.

Comment: This happens even if a multi-day appointment is not an all-day appointment (i.e. checkbox is off) and I have a start and end time in the appointment.